# why xhr request get stuck at pending status randomly?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have a web made on Laravel and sometimes some xhr request get stuck at pending status so a portion of the page doesn't load. This doesn't happen all the time and refreshing the page solve the issue but is very annoying. ¿Why is this happening?¿How can avoid this to happen?[image]